# isapi 3 - strip all query strings from domain and subpages

Tags: string, isapi, isapi-rewrite

I would like to know how to strip out all query strings, i.e.

```
domain.com/?a=123 -->> domain.com
```

And

```
domain.com/page.asp?b=456 -->> domain.com/page.asp
```

Comment: I've edited the formatting of your post a bit, but it is still rather unclear. Could you edit for additional clarity?

Answer (score 1):

Robert, I guess this is the third time I reply to your issue:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [NC,NS,R=301,L]
```

Believe me, I know that's a good rule, however we need to know other rules it may conflict with.